# Spring Boot Multi Module Gradle Build - Multiple "Fat Jars"

Tags: java, spring, gradle, spring-boot

our spring-boot project looks like the following

```
project
|__ build.gradle
|__ settings.gradle
   |__ module_a
   |__ module_b
   |__ ...
|__ module_a
|__ module_b
```

module_a contains only the SpringApplication class and a file application.properties

Running ./gradlew build works fine, but the problem is, for every module (about 10) gradle generates a fat jar including all dependencies.

We want to only have one far jar (in module a)

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.2.0.RELEASE'
        springLoadedVersion = '1.2.0.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        // NOTE: You should declare only repositories that you need here
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/release" }
        maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
        maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath("org.springframework:springloaded:${springLoadedVersion}")
    }
}


allprojects {

    group = "example.group"
    version = "0.0.1"

    repositories() {
        mavenCentral()
    }

}


subprojects {

    apply plugin: "groovy"
    apply plugin: "eclipse"

    eclipse {
        classpath {
            containers.remove("org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER")
            containers "org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8"
        }
    }

    apply plugin: "idea"
    apply plugin: "java"
    apply plugin: "spring-boot"

    mainClassName = "MainClassName"

    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    targetCompatibility = 1.8

    dependencies {
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) { gradleVersion = '2.2' }
```

We tried adding the options 
    jar.enabled = false
    bootRepackage.enabled = false

in the subprojects section, but after that, the project wont comile any longer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than applying the Spring Boot plugin to every sub-project, you could apply it only to `module_a`:

```
project(':module_a') {
    apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
}
```

Comment: My colleague told me, he already tried that approach, but the problem with this is, that the automatic version resolution does not work anymore. So instead of writing compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web") he had to write compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.2.0.RELEASE"). But I will try it again and provide feedback

Comment: Your colleague is correct: the automatic version resolution won't work with this approach. If you need the automatic version resolution, you were on the right lines with disabling repackaging but I don't think you need to disable jar as well.

Comment: Adding "bootRepackage.enabled = false" to all of our submodules worked for us. I accpeted your answer because this works fine too, if you dont rely on automatic version resolution. Thanks